# Customers who bought only this month and not before sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have a list of records of purchases and need to know the total users who bought in the current month, but have never bought in past months
date_buy = date of purchase

```
$hoy = date("Y-m-d");
$mesActual = date("Y-m-01");

SELECT count(DISTINCT(id_user)) 
        FROM transaction
        where date_buy BETWEEN '$mesActual' and '$hoy'
        AND date_buy >(select min(date_buy) FROM transaction)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible way is

```
 SELECT count(DISTINCT(id_user)) 
 FROM transaction t1
 WHERE date_buy BETWEEN '$mesActual' and '$hoy'
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM transaction t2 WHERE t2.id_user = t1.id_user AND t2.date_buy < '$mesActual')
```

Comment: Sql syntax do not allow for empty SELECT list. On the other hand [NOT] EXISTS returns nothing from the SELECT list. So any constant or column or * will do .

Answer (score 0):

Figure out your users that bought before the date and then restrict by their id_users'

```
    SELECT count(DISTINCT(id_user)) 
    FROM transaction
    where date_buy BETWEEN '$mesActual' and '$hoy'
    AND id_user NOT IN (select id_user FROM transaction where date_buy < '$mesActual')
```